# Paperclip validate .apk-file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to only be able to upload .apk files.
However, when I try this with an .apk file it is rejected.

What I have tried so far:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :app, :content_type => ['apk']
```

How do you do this? Perhaps there is a way to specify a regex for the file name (and extension) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
validates_attachment_content_type :app, :content_type => ['application/vnd.android.package-archive']
```

This is the actual mime type for apk files.

If that doesn't work, then remove the validation temporarily and upload an apk file.  See what the content_type is being stored as in the database and then use that as the string.  You may need to test with a variety of browsers in case there are differences.

Hope this helps.